# Probability Rabbit in a forest

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

We pick up 10 rabbits at random, the max weight among those 10 rabbits is A

we pick up 20 rabbits at random, the max weight among those 20 rabbits is B

If weights are distributed normally, N (m,v), what is the probability that A > B.

a) 1/2

b) 1/3

c) 1/3 * m/v

d) 1/sqrt(1*pi)

e) 1/4

My proposal is :

let : $X_{i}$ be the first 10 rabbits and $Y_{j}$ the 20 others rabbits

so :

$P(A > B ) = P(max(X_{i}) > max(Y_{j}))$

$=\prod_{j = 1}^{20}P(max(X_{i}) > Y_{j}) $

$=P(max(X_{i}) > Y)^{20} $   with Y ~ N(m,v)

$=(1 - P(max(X_{i}) < Y))^{20} $

$=(1 - \prod_{i= 1}^{10}P(max(X_{i}) < Y))^{20} $

$= (1-P(X < Y)^{10})^{20}$ with X ~ N(m,v)

Now I will calculate $P(X<Y)$

$P(X<Y) = P(Z < 0)$ with Z ~ $N(0,2*v)$

$= 0.5$

Finally

P(A > B ) = (1-0.5^10)^20 = 0.98

I come across with a different value

Can you help me ?

Comment: I take it the $10$ toward the end of the second paragraph is supposed to be $20$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions.

Comment: As already commented above, please fix the proposition "we pick up 20 rabbits at random, the max weight among those **10** rabbits is B"...

Comment: You ask, "what is the probability that $A < B$." But later you claim to compute $P(A > B).$ I think the question you received asked for the probability that $A > B,$ didn't it?

Comment: I don't know what you were thinking when you cobbled up the formula $(1 - 0.5^{10})^{20}.$ Clearly you have some misconception, but since you explain nothing in your method it is hard to know how to correct the misconception.

Comment: Hi gays, I edited my post, I hope it's clear for you now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the correction of the inequality there is a good solution.

You collected $30$ rabbits in total.  The question is which group the heaviest is in.  If the heaviest one is in the first group, we will have $A \gt B.  $As $\frac 13$ of the ones you collected are in the first group, the chance the heaviest one is in $A$ is $\frac 13$ and the answer is **b**.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, but you didn't use the fact that the weight is normally distributed. what do you think about the new change in my proposal ?

Comment: I did not use it because it doesn't matter.   As long as no two rabbits have exactly the same weight and they are sampled without replacement all we care about is the ranking.  You take the $30$ rabbits caught, line them up in order, and ask whether the heaviest is in the first $10$ or the last $20$.

Comment: Thank you for your solution, I think I was wrong, since they don't mentioned  that,what I called $X_{i}$,was independent.